# AngularJS: Sliding + fading animation when data content changes (Data is being loaded from server)

Tags: angularjs, animation

```
 I have an application where I load the data using Angular JS ng-repeat.
```

**HTML**

```
                  <my-card my-details="assignee"
                                 user-map="ctrl.usersMap">
                  </my-card>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**Animation CSS**

```
  .animate-enter,
  .animate-leave
  {
    -webkit-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -moz-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -ms-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -o-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  }

  .animate-enter {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    left: 0;
  }

  .animate-leave {
    left: 0;
  }
```

All the data is rendered here horizontally.

I have a next and previous button which is used to fetch next/previous batch of assignees from the rest service. I need to animate this fetch in way that it should slide smoothly to the left when fetching next batch of records and then to the right when fetching previous batch of records.

Please see screenshot below:
[Image-Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEOxw.png)

Comment: There is no question here. What have you tried so far? What problem do you want solved? People here are willing to help, but this is not a place to just give out assignments :) Also, there is no screenshot.

Comment: use https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations